# Port Forwarding on Arris NVG599 results in "pinhole conflict detected"

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, rdp

I am helping a small business that won't buy an actual router or firewall and is using the Arris NVG599 that AT&T provided them.

I have two port forwarding rules that need to be setup, 33891 > 3389 for Comp1 and 33892 > 2289 for Comp2.

I made both service objects and assigned 33891>3389 to Comp1 but when I try to assign 33892>3389 to Comp2 I get the error:

What we are trying to do is allow two remtoe users to RDP into their computers by RDPing to the WAN IP on ports 33891 & 33892.

> Pinhole conflict detected XXX
>
> Pinhole conflict detected XXX

Does anyone know if this is something that can be fixed? AT&T support basically said it's above their head and I would need to pay $100 for their "360" support. I get the feeling that the modem doesn't allow for the same port to be mapped to two different devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT&T's flash of the NVG599 does not support port forwarding where the same destination port routes to two devices.

The workaround was to change the RDP port on the second PC to something besides 3389 and create the port forward to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I wanted to use two different ports (external - incoming) but the same port internally and got the pin hole error.  The solution for Windows XP and newer (I did this in Windows 10) can be found here: http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/

You can leave one of your rules as-is - 33891 > 3389 but for 33892, point that to 33892 and then on that system, in the command prompt (Admin), enter:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=33892 listenaddress=(ip address of your system) connectport=3389 connectaddress=(ip address of your system)

Make sure your firewall settings allow for inbound 33892 and 3389.

I haven't reboot my system since using this solution so I don't know if I need to create a .bat file and add it to the startup or not.  But if it stops working after rebooting, you'll know what to do.